Как выделить границы тайлов в Unity?
Делаю программу на подобие редактора карт с использованием Grid и Tilemap. Поступила задача - необходимо выделять белым цветом границы всех тайлов на карте, чтобы пользователь мог видеть, какие тайлы доступны для заполнения блоками.

На изображении выше скриншот из вкладки с самой сценой. Примерно такого результата мне нужно добиться. На данный момент в режиме игры у меня просто синий фон, который хотелось бы поменять на сетку с режима сцены.

Каким образом проще всего это сделать? Посмотрел пару форумов и порылся на YouTube - инструкций по данному вопросу просто напросто не нашел. Буду благодарен любой помощи или совету!

Я бы на вашем месте начинал создавать карту не с космоса, а с заполнения какими-то блоками по умолчанию. Границы блока, линии, можно например отрисовывать только при нведении мыши на него, таким образом не будет необходимости рисовать линии по всей карте.

@aepot я понимаю, что так можно делать, но просто поступила задача именно выделить ВСЕ блоки границами

Ну в таком случае нужны прозрачные блоки. Либо линии по координатам отрисовать.

@aepot а нет какого-то туториала для отрисовки линий по границам тайлов? был бы очень благодарен за информацию по этой теме

Из простого, есть Line Renderer. Для нахождения вершин по которым нужно провести линию, особые знания не нужны. Разве что нужен волновой алгоритм, для разделения тайлов на не соединённые кластеры, у каждого из которых своя линия. Бумажка, листочек и простой пример из пары тайлов 4-5-6, расположенные как нибудь зигзагом по которым можно выработать алгоритм.
